# Can't get dynamic html page by using Self hosted AspNetCore MVC inside console app as Windows Service

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core, self-hosting

Problem: Need to be able to install and run Asp.Net MVC app (which returns a SPA angular app) as Windows Service

Subject: I'm using ASp.Net Core MVC inside Console app and run it as Windows service and it works perfectly fine (all requests are getting to the right place) but `return View();` returns empty page instead of the right html.

```
 public class Startup
{
    public IContainer ApplicationContainer { get; private set; }
    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; private set; }

    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            // This will push telemetry data through Application Insights pipeline faster, allowing you to view results immediately.
            builder.AddApplicationInsightsSettings(developerMode: true);
        }
        Configuration = builder.Build();

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);
        services.AddMvc().AddWebApiConventions();

        services.AddCors();

        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.Populate(services);

        this.ApplicationContainer = builder.Build();
        return new AutofacServiceProvider(this.ApplicationContainer);
    }

    // This method gets called at the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        app.UseApplicationInsightsRequestTelemetry();
        app.UseApplicationInsightsExceptionTelemetry();

        var listener = app.ServerFeatures.Get<WebListener>();
        if (listener != null)
        {
            listener.AuthenticationManager.AuthenticationSchemes =
            AuthenticationSchemes.NTLM;
        }

        app.UseFileServer();
        app.UseCors(builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin());

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            routes.MapWebApiRoute(
                name: "defaultApi",
                template: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static string ServiceName = "WebApp";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var exePath = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
    //sure it's not necessary! It was just a try 
directoryPath = directoryPath.Replace("\\bin", "");
            var directoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(exePath);
            var httpAddress = "https://localhost";
            var httpPort = "10778";
            var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseWebListener()
                .UseWebRoot(directoryPath + "\\wwwroot") //also just a try to navigate it right
                .UseContentRoot(directoryPath)
                .UseUrls($"{httpAddress}:{httpPort}")
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();

            if (Debugger.IsAttached || args.Contains("--debug"))
            {
                host.Run();
            }
            else
            {
                host.RunAsService();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var exMessage = ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

The sample project can be downloaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/eb8gs2xhlnawpd6/AAD_nqWjWsVL3Bskm0fttd6xa?dl=0)

**UPDATE:**

After including  app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage(); into Configure method get such list of the errors

[image]

Comment: I am getting `Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing, Version=1.0.0.0` error when trying to run your code. Gonna look into this.

Comment: after restoring all nuget packages project should work just fine, but you can also download them from [this source](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6rte3wlseo1bi0i/AAB188Px9f9agT7LPKTv-axua?dl=0)

Comment: Can you include your App.config file into the source code?

Comment: sure! i've updated the source

Comment: It looks like i have to include all the references i added by nuget to the app.config file. maybe you know the way how to do it automatically?

Comment: Seems like you are mixing up .Net and .Net Core framework assemblies... Normally assembly binding is added to App.config automatically, unless there is something unusual...
Since your application is targeting .Net 4.6.1, why don't you try to use the standard .Net MVC rather than .Net Core MVC?

Comment: the main reason is to have self hosted webapp without iis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new .NET Core Web Application targeting .NET v4.6.1. See screenshot below.

[image]

This way you will get an `exe` web application by default, and it targets .NET v4.6.1.

Comment: Interesting stuff!!, but unfortunately i have to use .net 4.6.1.

Comment: Can you clarify your question then?
Do you need a console app, or windows service? Your current code shows you are building a console app.
If you targeting .net 4.6.1 do you need .net core MVC, or standard .net MVC is enough?

Comment: Ok. I have a self hosted web api which works with windows enviroment and accessible by requests from browser. Now I need to save all that behavior (and I do it really fine with current sample implementation) and add to that angular based SPA to be able to configure that web api service behavior. Is this explanation clear or you might need some additional info?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I think it's actually easier than I thought! Just updated my answer. Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! In general it is good enought, but if things a bit more complicated it cause some annoying problems, so i decided to use another architectual aproach to solve my problem. thanks anyway!